# Python. Mostrar el índice de los números pares

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de separar los números pares introducidos por el usuario y separados con espacios con el método split(). Debo mostrar el índice de cada número par, no el número par en sí que es lo que yo consigo.

```
numeros = input('Introduce una cadena separada por espacios: ').split()
pares = []

for numero in numeros:
    if int(numero) % 2 == 0:
        pares = numero
        print(pares)
```

Y esta sería la otra versión que consigo, pero que me muestra los resultados en formato lista sin conseguir mostrar el índice.
¿A alguien se le ocurre como puedo solucionarlo?

```
numeros = input('Introduce una cadena separada por espacios: ').split()
pares = []

for numero in numeros:
    if int(numero) % 2 == 0:
        pares.append(numero)
print(pares)
```

Resultado

Introduce una cadena separada por espacios:
10 4 7 8 6 5

['10', '4', '8', '6']

Answer (score 0):

Cuando te piden el índice, es señal de que tienes que iterar con un `range(len(numeros))`.

Dentro de la iteración ya tienes el índice, con el cual puedes recuperar el entero ingresado para ver si es par o no. Si es par, agregas el índice a la lista.

```
numeros = input('Introduce una cadena separada por espacios: ').split()
pares = []

for indice in range(len(numeros)):
    numero = numeros[indice]
    if int(numero) % 2 == 0:
        pares.append(indice)

print(pares)
```

produce:

```
Introduce una cadena separada por espacios: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

Introduce una cadena separada por espacios: 1 3 5 7
[]

Introduce una cadena separada por espacios: 2 4 6 8 10
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Anteriormente había probado a hacerlo bastante similar a tu código, lo que pasa que tengo que devolver cada índice en un print.

Comment: @Janire. Coloca el `print` bajo el `if`.

Comment: Gracias. Necesito mostrar sólo el número del índice y lo que consigo así es que me muestre los índices en formato lista.

Comment: @Janire Está en formato lista porque pueden haber ninguno, uno, o muchos números pares en una cadena. El algoritmo resuelve el problema, ya es otra cuestión cómo quieres imprimirlos en la salida.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer se consigue muy fácil con la función `enumerate`. Es una función que viene por defecto en Python. Tu código está bien sólo tienes que cambiar un par de cosas. [Leer más aquí.](https://micro.recursospython.com/recursos/la-funcion-enumerate.html#:%7E:text=()%20%2D%20Recursos%20Python-,La%20funci%C3%B3n%20enumerate(),el%20segundo%2C%20el%20elemento%20mismo.) Pero en síntesis esta es la estructura de la función `enumerate(iterable, start)` donde el `iterable` es la lista que quieres enumerar, y el `start` el índice de inicio dónde quieres empezar a enumerar. Si no proporcionas `start` por defecto es el índice 0. `enumerate(iterable, start=0)`

```py
nums = input('Ingresa los números separados por un espacio: ')

# Se crea la lista de números 
nums = nums.split(' ')

# La lista de índices
lista_de_indices = []

# Al usar enumerate tenemos que usar 2 variables, la primera será el índice y la segunda el número en esa posición.
for index, numero in enumerate(nums):
    # Comprobamos que el número sea par
    if int(numero) % 2 == 0:
        # Si es par, su índice se añade a la lista.
        lista_de_indices.append(index)

print(lista_de_indices)
```

Como ves en el ejemplo. Cuando usas enumerate en el for necesitas especificar 2 variables. La primera siempre será el índice y la segunda el objeto en esa posición.

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es muy fácil, para eso solo hacemos uso de la función `list.index(elemet)` el cual nos devuelve el índice del elemento que deseamos. Según tu código.

```py
numeros = input('Introduce una cadena separada por espacios: ').split()
#pares = []

for numero in numeros:
    if int(numero) % 2 == 0:
        #pares.append(numero)
        indice = numeros.index(numero)
        print(f"El indice del numero par es {indice}")
#print(pares)
```

**Probamos**

```
Introduce una cadena separada por espacios: 2 4 5 6 7 8
El indice del numero par es 0
El indice del numero par es 1
El indice del numero par es 3
El indice del numero par es 5
```

No sé si aun quieres guardar los números en una lista, si lo quieres hacer descomentas esas líneas y si quieres saber el índice según la lista `pares` lo haces de igual forma con un ciclo `for`.